# jquery sortable - prevent duplicates between 2 lists

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

as in the title, how can I prevent duplicates between 2 lists. I am trying to stop duplicates in the #selected list. I suspect its done in the receive event but i am not having any luck.

```
    $(function () {

    $("#options").sortable({
        connectWith: $("#selected"),
        helper: 'original',
        revert: true,
        tolerance: "pointer",
    });

    $("#selected").sortable({
        connectWith: $("#options"),
        helper: 'original',
        receive: function (event, ui) {            
        },
    });

    $("#options,#selected").disableSelection();

    $("#SkillGroups").change(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Contractor/Contractor/GetSkillsBySkillGroup",
            data: { skillGroupId: $("#SkillGroups").val() },
            success: function (result) {
                $loadList(result);
            }
        })
    });
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Finally worked it out. A bit obvious when you see the solution. There are probably other ways to do this as well.

```
 $("#selected").sortable({
        connectWith: $("#options"),
        helper: 'original',
        receive: function (event, ui) {

            var identicalItemCount  = $("#selected").children('li:contains(' + ui.item.text() + ')').length;
            alert(identicalItemCount);
            if (identicalItemCount > 1) {
                alert("Ahem.... we have a duplicate!!");
                $("#selected").children('li:contains(' + ui.item.text() + ')').first().remove();
            }
        },
    });
```

Comment: very nice. I'm wondering why the function i suggested isn't doing what it purports to do, though.

Answer (score 0):

use jquery.unique() [HERE](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.unique/). removes duplicates from array of DOM elements.

```
    var l = $('#options, #selected').find('li').get();

    var lists = jQuery.unique(l);

    // build your new lists w/ $('#options').html() etc...
```

**EDIT**

[HERE'S a working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tpressley1/mBsFR/)

So what you need to make sure when you're calling this method, you're doing so on an array of DOM elements, and not strings or numbers. also, make sure you're using the JQuery alias ($) instead of the JQuery.methodName. The example included works, and the only thing left to do is tie this to Elements that are created from your load list function, then spit them back out into their respective uls once filtered.

Comment: I tried this on the receive event of the #selected list and it doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I checked the fiddle and there are still duplicates in the final list. li#o3 and li#s3 are still duplicated.

Comment: Well, this is one way to eliminate the dups, but the issue with this method is that it will completely destroy whatever order the user has put their items in... this sorta defeats the purpose of using jQuery UI-Sortable in the first place, doesn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the same solution if you want to do it based on checking data-* attributes. I just ran into this, hope it helps someone.

```
receive: function (event, ui) {

    var identicalItemCount  = $(this).children("li[data-yourattribue='" + somevalue + "']").length;
    //alert(identicalItemCount);
    if (identicalItemCount > 1) {
        //alert("Ahem.... we have a duplicate!!");
        $(this).children("li[data-yourattribue='" + somevalue + "']").last().remove();
    } else {

        //your other stuff (like ajax calls, etc..)

    }

},
```

If you do some ajax like saving some additional data in the session along with the dropped items, it can also be useful to delete the actually dropped droppable, and not the one present in the system already, using .last().

Answer (score 0):

No need to do any thing more or custom coding here is best concept to implement easily

```js
(function($) {
     
    $('.acd').sortable({
        connectWith: 'ul',
        receive: function(ev, ui) {
            if(ui.item.hasClass("number"))
              ui.sender.sortable("cancel");
        }
    });    
})(jQuery);
```

```css
h2 { font-size:1.4em; margin: 20px 10px 0 20px; }
ul
{
    float: left;
    margin: 20px 10px 0 20px;
    border:1px solid #999;
    width: 100px;
    padding:10px;
    list-style-type:none;
}
li
{
    background: #fff;
    border: solid 1px #ccc;
    font-family: Arial, Tahoma, San-Serif;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https:////ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"/>

<h2>In this snippet the right column does not append the numeric items from left column</h2>
<ul id="list1" class="acd">
    <li>One</li>
    <li class="number">2</li>
    <li class="number">3</li>
</ul>
<ul id="list2" class="acd">
    <li>Four</li>
    <li>Five</li>
    <li>Six</li>
</ul>
```

Thanks to Majid Azani who provided the best solution with Demo Link https://codepen.io/mj_azani/pen/npohF