# how to remove data in channel name using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
$(function() {

    $(".track").draggable({
      containment:"document",
      appendTo:document.body,
      connectToSortable:"#playlist tbody",
      revert: true,
      revertDuration: 0,
      cursor: "move", 
      helper: "clone",
      cursorAt: { top: 17, left: 80 },
      start: function(event, ui) {
      },
      drag: function(event, ui) {

      }
    });

    $("#playlist tbody").droppable({
      hoverClass: "ui-active",
      accept:".track",
      drop: function( event, ui ) {
        if($("#playlist tbody .nothing")) $("#playlist tbody .nothing").remove();//.style.display="none";
      }
    }).sortable({
      appendTo: document.body,
      cursor: "move", 
      helper: "clone",
      cursorAt: { top: 17, left: 80 },
    });
    $('.remove-td').click(function () {
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
});
  });
```

How to delete data from which will present after onclick '✖' mark after drag and drop using jquery or javascript.
below is the link of working js fiddle
[Js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5ekhtyrg/)

Comment: It took me a while to understand what you are asking. You may want to elaborate a bit better to make your question clearer. This will improve your chances of getting a helpful answer.

Comment: can you not use the same `.remove()` that you used for "Shows" column ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add new function in your javascript like

```
function removeRow(obj){       
   $(obj).parent().parent().remove();
    //or
   $(obj).closest(".track").remove();
}
```

remove below Code

```
$('.remove-td').click(function () {
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
});
```

Add removeRow function call to your all X

```
<tr class="track"><td>Track 1<button onclick="removeRow(this)" class="remove-td" style="float:right;">✖</button></td></tr>
```

Comment: now how to disable delete in left hand side...  i.e. Shows column

Comment: is their any way bro

Comment: please check update fiddle. i have just added css to hide x button left side. i have not added removerow code in it.  https://jsfiddle.net/5ekhtyrg/1/

Comment: no no.......  I have two columns, "Shows" and "Channel Name", i should not be able to delete items in "Shows" column

Comment: please check fiddle and let me know if i am right or not

Comment: yup that what i'm looking for mate, but in updated fiddle i am not able to delete items in column "Channel Name"

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/5ekhtyrg/3/ please check now and do not forgot to accept the answer if it works for you :)

Comment: thank you mate and 1) can i keep some default height to column "Channel Name" after i drag and drop, because once i drop item it becomes small , and 2) can i drop only unique items from column "Shows" into column "Channel Name", without removing items permanently from column "Shows". and thank you for the help so far .....

Answer (score 0):

You are using elements dynamically. Therefore the click function must be defined in a different way.

```
$(document).on('click', '.remove-td', function () {
  $(this).parent().parent().remove();
});
```

Comment: one more thing is i don't to want drag and drop same items into channel name.. is their any way

Comment: I would remove the item from the Shows list when it is added to the Channel Name list

Comment: No , because i will be having multiple columns (like Channel name 1, Channel name 2, Channel name 3...) where i need to drag and drop, so i cant do that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use **event-delegation** approach to attach an event handler to the element.

```
$('#wrapPls').on('click', '.remove-td', function () {
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

> Do not use `$(this).parent().parent().remove()` as it will remove the `<tr>` and you will NOT be able to drop anymore into Channel name column.

Comment: thank you... its working .... one more thing is i don't to want drag and drop same items into channel name.. is their any way  ??

Comment: Yes I guess. You could use the `accept:` function to achieve it.

Comment: Here I found these links. Maybe useful [first](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9279380/jquery-droppable-avoid-multiple-drops-of-the-same-object), [second](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25769272/prevent-duplicated-item-in-jqueryui-sortable), [third](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15668524/jquery-sortable-prevent-duplicates-between-2-lists). Using `receive:` and `accept:` functions